# Getting Part file name when uploading file for web app

Tags: file, jakarta-ee, file-upload

I'm uploading a file that is a zip in a web app and passing it as type "Part" and I need to grab the name of the file that I originally uploaded. I can't seem to figure out for the life of me how to grab the actual name of the uploaded file. I've tried the following assuming my Part is uploaded with the original file name as "ABCD". My Part object will be named "file":

file.getHeaderNames() yields "content-type" and "content-disposition"

file.getName() yields "BPzip8237267963573706108tmp" which is the temp file's name

Any ideas on how I would go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// define variable for file name
String filename = "";

// get part
Part file = request.getPart("file");

// get filename from part header
for (String s: file.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
    if (s.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
        filename = s.split("=")[1].replace("\"", "");
        break;
    }
}
```